# <br> is inserted into contenteditable html element if left empty

Tags: html

I have a `<div contenteditable="true"></div>` and when I enter some content into it, then **delete** these content, it seems like the browser is inserting a `<br>` element automatically into this element.

Does anyone has any experience with this? Know how to fix it?

Comment: What browser does this happen in?

Comment: Under what circumstances? Are you modifying the file, or just messing with the dom in console or something?

Comment: A div should always separate itself, equivalent to <br>s, because it is a block element.

Comment: @njk I notice it in Chrome so far.

Comment: @KaiQing Neither. contenteditable allows you to add content directly into the div from the browser.

Comment: facing the same problem please share if anyone has a solution.

Answer (score 20):

**Use SPAN element as your contenteditable element instead of DIV element.**

Please read complete.
Q. Why the idea works?
A. Span is an inline element and Div is a block element. Block elements when empty, by default, will have zero dimensions(if no padding is applied to the block element). In contrast, empty inline elements tend to maintain their height and width becomes zero.
Hence, we just need to provide proper width to this Span(or any inline element), but, an inline element won't take width as a property and therefore we need to specify the display of this inline element as inline-block or block.

I have extensively used this idea for creating online-editors. Hope this helps.

NOTE: On changing display of an inline element to block/inline-block, doesn't mean the nature of element has changed. It is still an inline element, so an inline element will never be able to hold a block element inside it.

Comment: Forgot to mention. No BR will be added to span element when empty because they maintain their height.

Comment: Thanks, replacing the div with span solved my problem.

Comment: Interestingly, you can still have multi-line editors with this approach. The browser will add `<br>` tags when you press `Enter`, just not when you press `Space`.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue before developing a feature for a web app. It's a default behavior for browsers. It's the same as a line break for text editors. Best way to handle it is to run a RegEx on the content when submitting/grabbing it to remove the tags, and then blanking it when no text is available.

I typically use the <br> tags to figure out where my line breaks are. Some browsers use <p> tags, so be sure to cross-browser test it.

Comment: Thanks. Currently I'm just checking for content as `<br>` and treat it as a case for empty to go around it. Seems kinda hackish. Wondering if there's a nicer solution to it.

Answer (score 3):

Another way around this problem is to change the behavior of how the white space is handled inside the element. Use CSS:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Check out [this link](https://codepen.io/star_coder/pen/VXJPmz) for both the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happened to me when the callback of $(window).KeyUp event returned no value.
Once applying "return true" in the registered callback the contenteditable div stopped applying unnecessary br tags.

Answer (score 1):

Just found an easy CSS solution to not display new lines :

```
.myEditable br
  {
  display: none;
  }
.myEditable div
  {
  display: inline;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running with same problem when i make a element content editable i figure out a 
 is inserted at the point i make element contenteditable at same time i remove breaks from the element. That perfectly worked for me.

```
 myselect.attr('contenteditable', 'true'); 
 myselect.find('br').remove();
```

Comment: No, if you execute `myselect.find('br').remove();`, it removes all <br> which is not good it's better to remove last `<br>` by chinging it to `myselect.find("br:last-child")`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine for me. If you want to remove the whitespace you can use:

```
str = $('div[contenteditable="true"]');
str.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, '');
```

If you want to remove the <br> you can use:

```
str = $('div[contenteditable="true"]');
str.replace(/<br>/gi, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to reproduce this. **No matter what type of element is**, contenteditable element will be inserted into a `<br>` element when all element node in it is empty(`textContent===''`)

Here provide a stable example which can reproduce this:

```
<p
      style={{ padding: 10 }}
      contentEditable tabIndex={1}>
      <span></span>
      {"123"}
      <span></span>
    </p>
```

Change element type from `p` to `span` can not solve the problem.

So the suggestion is check empty element and remove it in advance.