# How can I detect a HTML change inside a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'v a problem with my contenteditable div. I am currently trying to detect any change in my div element. This works quite well so far. But it fails when I change the content via jQuery:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  let input = $("#input");

  input.on("input", function() {
    console.log($(this).html().length);
  });

  $("button").click(function() {
    input.html(input.html() + `<span class="emoji"></span>`);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block;
  color: #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input" placeholder="Schreib eine Nachricht..." contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true"></div>
<button>Add element to contenteditable div</button>
```

How can I solve this problem? I could do this check inside my click event but I need to add a lot of them so I don't want to do this every time. In this case I think it's better to do it in one input check function.

Comment: Well if you're adding it via jquery, why can't you just trigger whatever function you'd normally want to trigger when normally typing?

Comment: @GBWDev I thought the same. So I've changed my question a bit at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you will need to trigger the event you're listening to yourself:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  let input = $("#input");

  input.on("input", function() {
    console.log($(this).html().length);
    
    // Contenteditable adds a <br> when empty.
    // Solutions on SO appear not to work
    if (!$(this).text()) {
      console.log('cleared editable');
      input.html('');
    }
  });

  $("button").click(function() {
    input.html(input.html() + `<span class="emoji"></span>`);
    input.trigger('input');
  });
});
```

```css
[contenteditable=true] {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block;
  color: #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input" placeholder="Schreib eine Nachricht..." contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true"></div>
<button>Add element to contenteditable div</button>
```

Comment: Oh now I've found another problem. If I delete the content of the div now manually, ad <br> element will be left. Is this affected by the trigger?

Comment: @Mr.Jo This is a general issue with contenteditable, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638887/br-is-inserted-into-contenteditable-html-element-if-left-empty

Comment: Oh okay. It looks like this can't be fix. I've tried "Use SPAN element as your contenteditable element instead of DIV element." but the problem is still there. But thanks for your input trigger help thing :)

Comment: @Mr.Jo Hm yes odd, I've added a possible solution - using text() (aka innerText in native JS) to see if it resolves to an empty string (which br does) and clearing it

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to add function inside your `.click()` listener you could achieve your effect by using [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  let input = $("#input");

  input.on("input", function() {
    console.log($(this).html().length);
  });

  $("button").click(function() {
    input.html(input.html() + `<span class="emoji"></span>`);
  });
  
  
  const targetNode = document.getElementById('input');
  const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
  const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
    for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
        }
        else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
  
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block;
  color: #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input" placeholder="Schreib eine Nachricht..." contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true"></div>
<button>Add element to contenteditable div</button>
```

I don't think this is most optimal way, maybe you should rethink your architecture. But I'm sure this one will fit your requirements.