# Why is there an unknown <br> after I copy/paste between two contenteditable divs?

Tags: html, contenteditable

```js
$('.cedit').on('input', function(){
  console.log($(this).html());
});
```

```css
.cedit{background:#eee; outline:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='cedit' contenteditable>
<div>lorem</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class='cedit' contenteditable>
<div>ipsum</div>
</div>
```

pls drag the mouse and select `lorem` and go - Ctrl-C

then drag the mouse and select `ipsum` and go - Ctrl-V

why there is a `<br>` inside the result - it didn't exist anywhere before - and how to avoid it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<br> is inserted into contenteditable html element if left empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638887/br-is-inserted-into-contenteditable-html-element-if-left-empty)

Comment: @HereticMonkey - there is no solution on your link

Comment: Did you try using a `<span>` instead of a `<div>`, [as mentioned in the highest scoring answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50059064/215552)?

Comment: @HereticMonkey - `span` is not suitable for my entire page scenario